# Swift - Dynamic sound button system

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I tried looking around this forum but I can't find much information on this specific problem that I have. What I would like is to dynamically play sounds when a button is pressed.

Here's what I have so far below:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    var collectionView: UICollectionView?

    func callSoundURL(soundFile: String) -> NSURL {
        let soundURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(soundFile, withExtension: "mp3")!
        return soundURL
    }
    var soundPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    func playMySound(soundURL: NSURL) {

        do { soundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL, fileTypeHint: nil) } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }

        soundPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1
        soundPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        soundPlayer.play()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let row = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        var fileLabel: String
        fileLabel = "beep"
        let soundURLMade: NSURL = callSoundURL(fileLabel)
        playMySound(soundURLMade)
    }
}
```

There's a lot more of the code that is not revealed because it's not pertinent to what I'm trying to do right now but I can supply more if it's needed.

Essentially, I have a collectionview and when a user clicks on a cell, I want the system to play a sound. The file name for each cell will be taken from an array. The problem right now however is that I can't even get a static sound file to play.

When a cell is pressed, the fileLabel is a string that is passed into the function to convert it into an object that has the location of the file, sent back out, then goes into playing the file.

The error that I'm getting is here (in the callSoundURL function):

```
let soundURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(soundFile, withExtension: "mp3")!
```

The error during the debug session is bad_instruction

If anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried taking the ! out and replacing it with a ?. Then check to make sure that soundURL is not null. It could be that it is not finding the file you are looking for.

let soundURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(soundFile, withExtension: "mp3")?

Comment: Oh wow. You're correct about the file being in the wrong place. I placed it in a folder under the main dir. I assumed it would work because it has been working like this in other projects. I feel so dumb. Thank you so much!